# Get write18 to accept / expand command

Tags: external-files, programming, shell-escape

I am trying to use write18 to crop a pdf. The code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\filename}{}
\newcommand{\croppedfilename}{}

\begin{document}

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\filename}{mypath/myimage.pdf}
    \filename@parse{mypath/myimage.pdf}
    \renewcommand{\croppedfilename}{\filename@area\filename@base.cropped.\filename@ext}
    \makeatother

    filename: \filename

    croppedfilename: \croppedfilename

    \immediate\write18{pdfcrop mypath/myimage.pdf \croppedfilename}%

    \immediate\write18{pdfcrop \filename \croppedfilename}%

    \the\pdfshellescape

\end{document}
```

Here `\the\pdfshellescape` is 1.

The line `\immediate\write18{pdfcrop mypath/myimage.pdf \croppedfilename}` does produce my cropped pdf, but `\immediate\write18{pdfcrop \filename \croppedfilename}` does not. Of course I need the second version in order to put it into a command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check the log, you'll see

```
runsystem(pdfcrop mypath/myimage.pdf mypath/myimage.cropped.pdf)...executed.

runsystem(pdfcrop mypath/myimage.pdfmypath/myimage.cropped.pdf)...executed.
```

Notice the lack of a space in the second line. What's happening is the usual TeX behaviour of skipping spaces after macro names: in your case `\filename`. Thus you need to make sure a space is 'seen' there:

```
\immediate\write18{pdfcrop \filename\space\croppedfilename}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does however not work in a function... I made a new question, because I did not ask this specifically here and the reason seems to be the parsing: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417373/get-write18-to-execute-after-file-parsing