# Get write18 to execute after file parsing

Tags: external-files, programming, shell-escape

*Follow up to* [Get write18 to accept / expand command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417367/get-write18-to-accept-expand-command/417368#417368)

---

I want to crop a pdf and print it. My `\the\pdfshellescape` is 1, so my shell-escape is working. My MWE is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\filename}{}
\newcommand{\croppedfilename}{}
\newcommand{\includecroppedgraphics}[1]{%
    \makeatletter
    \filename@parse{#1}
    \renewcommand{\filename}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\croppedfilename}{\filename@area\filename@base.cropped.\filename@ext}
    \makeatother
    \immediate\write18{pdfcrop #1 \croppedfilename}%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\croppedfilename}}
}

\begin{document}

    \includecroppedgraphics{mypath/myimage.pdf}

    \the\pdfshellescape

\end{document}
```

This does not produce the cropped image. From the log I get

> runsystem(pdfcrop mypath/myimage.pdf mypath/myimage.pdf@areamypath/myimage.pdf@
>   base.cropped.mypath/myimage.pdf@ext)...executed.

Obviously the parsing I got from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39636/49283 did not work even though it *did* work in [Get write18 to accept / expand command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417367/get-write18-to-accept-expand-command/417368#417368)

How do I get the parsing right here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few errors to fix:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}

\newcommand{\filename}{}
\newcommand{\croppedfilename}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\includecroppedgraphics}[1]{%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \edef\croppedfilename{\filename@area\filename@base.cropped.\filename@ext}%
  \immediate\write18{pdfcrop #1 \croppedfilename}%
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\croppedfilename}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includecroppedgraphics{mypath/myimage.pdf}

\end{document}
```

1. `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` must surround a definition using `@`-commands
2. `\renewcommand` is not good for `\croppedfilename`, you have to fully expand everything in the replacement text
3. `grffile` is needed for multiple periods in the file name
4. Don't forget to protect end-of-lines

Comment: My pdf has different pages and I want each page to be cropped individually, since I am going to use `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, page=#1]`. Currently small images are still only cropped as much as other pages that have larger images.

Comment: @Make42 That's quite a different problem

Comment: Should I post a new question, or is this not a LaTeX question?

Comment: @Make42 If I do `pdfcrop` on a multipage document, a single PDF file is created where every page is cropped differently according to the page contents; if I later include the pages with `\includegraphics[page=<n>]{file.pdf}`, I get the expected bounding boxes.

Comment: https://onetransistor.blogspot.de/2016/01/pdf-crop-linux-software.html says that pdfcrop is not able to do this - maybe we are using different versions? I am using pdfcrop 2012/11/02 v1.38

Comment: @Make42 The same as I'm using.

Comment: Seems there is something else going on - I guess it is because of my pdf itself. So what worked however was krop (version 0.5.0) http://arminstraub.com/software/krop - but also only if each page is processed individually. So I wrote a script to do this. It works when I call it from the command line interface. But when I call the script from latex, it does not work anymore.

Comment: I added another question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417391/exectue-external-bash-file