# Execute external bash file

Tags: external-files, programming, shell-escape

This is a follow up to [Get write18 to execute after file parsing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417373/49283)

---

With the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}

\newcommand{\filename}{}
\newcommand{\croppedfilename}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\includecroppedgraphics}[1]{%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \edef\croppedfilename{\filename@area\filename@base.cropped.\filename@ext}%
  \immediate\write18{pdfcrop #1 \croppedfilename}%
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\croppedfilename}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includecroppedgraphics{mypath/myimage.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I tried to crop a PDF. This did not work for my mutli-page PDF.
What did work was the script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

temdirname="./croppedpages"

mkdir "$temdirname"
pdftk "$1" burst output "$temdirname"/Page_%03d.pdf

while read -d $'\0' pdfpage ; do
    krop --go --autotrim -o "$pdfpage" "$pdfpage"
done < <(find "$temdirname" -print0)

pdftk "$temdirname"/*.pdf output "$2"
rm -R "$temdirname"
```

that I wrote based on

- https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/pdftk/
- http://arminstraub.com/software/krop

But it only works so far from the command line. Now I want to include it into the LaTeX script, but the call does not work. I thought I could simply change

`\immediate\write18{pdfcrop #1 \croppedfilename}%`

to

`\immediate\write18{splitcropmerge.sh #1 \croppedfilename}%`

In the log it says

> runsystem(splitcropmerge.sh Pakete-Uebersicht/Pakete-Uebersicht.pdf Pakete-Uebe
>   rsicht/Pakete-Uebersicht.cropped.pdf)...executed.
>
> LaTeX Warning: File `Pakete-Uebersicht/Pakete-Uebersicht.cropped.pdf' not found
>    on input line 187.

---

Krop was installed from package from arminstraub.com/downloads/krop/krop_0.5.0-1_all.deb according to https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/krop-debian-8-ubuntu-16-04-pdf-crop-tool with

```
sudo dpkg -i krop_0.5.0-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Probably because you are missing the shell in `\immediate\write18{splitcropmerge.sh #1 \croppedfilename}%`. You should specify the shell before the script name: `\immediate\write18{bash splitcropmerge.sh #1 \croppedfilename}%`

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I tested your code after commenting the `while` loop that you use `krop`.

What is inside the `\write18` command is executed exactly like if you typed it in the command prompt. If you execute:

```bash
splitcropmerge.sh mypath/myimage.pdf mypath/myimage.cropped.pdf
```

you'll get an error from the shell. If, on the other hand, you run:

```bash
bash splitcropmerge.sh mypath/myimage.pdf mypath/myimage.cropped.pdf
```

it will work (if the files exist, of course).

So do the same in the line with the `\write18`:

```tex
\immediate\write18{bash splitcropmerge.sh #1 \croppedfilename}%
```

As noted by @RobtAll, LuaLaTeX users might need to `\usepackage{shellesc}`. LuaLaTeX (0.87 onwards) doesn't have the same output streams that TeX had, so 18 can be any file. The package `shellesc` provides the `\ShellEscape` macro to replace TeX's `\write18`:

```tex
\ShellEscape{bash splitcropmerge.sh #1 \croppedfilename}%
```

Comment: Also, lualatex users might need `\usepackage{shellesc}`.

Comment: you only need the explicit `bash` if the shell script is not executable and on the path, normally if you write a shell script you would make it executable, so `bash` would not be needed